# Azure Data Factory Get Filepaths of nested json objects

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage, azure-data-lake, azure-storage-files

I have the following problem in Azure Data Factory:

container/../../year=2023/m=1/d=01/h=01/m=5/file.json

There is a json file for every 5 minutes, every hour, every day, every month in the year 2023.
I want to get a list of all the filepaths. So that I can loop through them and copy the json data.

How can I do that?

I tried the get Metadata activity. However, this does not work recursively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As get metadata does not support the recursive iteration.

An alternative to attempting a direct recursive traversal is to take an iterative approach, using a queue implemented in ADF as an Array variable. You can follow above documentation to create this iterative approach.

@Richard Swinbank here Get Metadata recursively in Azure Data Factory  [document](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/get_metadata_recursively_in_azure_data_factory)  discussed the Workaround for same situation.

> I want to get a list of all the filepaths. So that I can loop through them and copy the json data.

To copy data using dataflow or copy activity you can just use wild cards to copy files recursively.

[image]